# PHP strtotime timezone issue with '0:00 GMT'

Tags: php, timezone, strtotime

So I have a function `get_start_of_day($time)`, which I want to give me a timestamp representing the very very first minute of the day in which `$time`, a timestamp, falls.

Originally, I was using:

```
 function get_start_of_day($time) {
     return strtotime('0:00 GMT', $time);
 }
```

which seemed to be working just fine.

Then I realized that for certain times it was returning midnight of the previous day, for example:

```
$x = 1432468800;
echo gmdate('Y-M-d H:i:s', $x);
$y = get_start_of_day($x);
echo gmdate('Y-M-d H:i:s', $y);
```

outputs:

```
2015-May-24 12:00:00
2015-May-24 00:00:00
```

BUT:

```
$x = 1432432800;
echo gmdate('Y-M-d H:i:s', $x);
$y = get_start_of_day($x);
echo gmdate('Y-M-d H:i:s', $y);
```

outputs:

```
2015-May-24 02:00:00
2015-May-23 00:00:00
```

So at some value for $x, the output was wrongly jumping to the day previous and outputting that. Some further experimentation revealed that the value for $x at which the jump happens is 4am, i.e. the timestamp `1432440000` gave the proper result, but the timestamp `1432439999` did not.

Now, according to Epoch Converter I'm in GMT-4:00. It seems as though this must somehow be the cause. I've updated the function to:

```
 function get_start_of_day($time) {
     $start_of_day = strtotime('tomorrow 0:00 GMT', $time);
     if ($start_of_day > $time) {
         $start_of_day -= 86400;
     }
     return $start_of_day;
 }
```

which seems to work fine, but I can't help but wonder...what's going on here? Does anybody know?

Thanks in advance! :)

EDIT: I'm using GMT in case I move to a new server...I would hate to be getting different start-of-day values after I hypothetically move, which may not sync up with the old values. So I figured, just use GMT for everything, all the time.

Comment: probably your system timezone is not in GMT. so if the time you're checking is inside +/- your timezone offset, you'd get values you aren't expecting.

Comment: ...So is that the function you're using now? If so, could you be a little clearer ("Originally I was using" => "My current, but broken, function is") and maybe format that last bit as actual code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `strtotime('today', $time)`. You will need to use [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) or [date.timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone) INI setting to select your time zone.

Comment: If I use `'today'` then I get timezone-specific timestamps. Won't this mean that my start-of-day timestamps will get out of sync if I use a different server in a different time zone?

Comment: That's why I was thinking it would be best to use GMT for everything.

Comment: Using UTC (not GMT) for everything is very nice. See above for `date_default_timezone_set`.

Comment: `date_default_timezone_set('UTC')` worked! date.timezone did not (in Drupal, using `ini_set('date.timezone', 'UTC')` in my settings.php file).